# How to get a char * arr[] from a managed array<String^>^?

Tags: arrays, string, c++-cli, marshalling, wrapper

I'm a bit confused how to get a `char * Bar[]` of an `array<String^>^`.

My unmanaged function look's kinda this:

```
void NativeClass::Foo(char * Bar[])
{
    SomeAPIFunction(Bar);
}
```

Managed Part (should only give an idea of what i am trying to achieve):

```
void ManagedClass::Foo(array<String^>^ Bar)
{
    NativeClass * MyNativeClass = new NativeClass();
    MyNativeClass->Foo(Bar);
}
```

- Found `pin_ptr`. Can't get it to work.
- For `String^` to `char *` i use this: `char * NewFoo = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Foo);`. Maybe there is an opportunity to go in such a way?
- I can't change the `SomeAPIFunction(Bar)`.
- The size of my managed `Bar` is not fixed.

Comment: Why don't you use `String::c_str()`?

Comment: You know how to get a `char*` from a `String^`, that's a good start. Now what about getting e.g. a `std::vector<char*>` from an `array<String^>^`? If you can do that then you practically have what you need. Oh and by the way, why are you dynamically allocating `MyNativeClass`? Lastly, don't forget to free the strings you create!

Comment: I'm still on it, but just to clarify, the "managed part" example is for reference only, i have to init `MyNativeClass`. And i'm doing "manual GC" too; but i think for my problem this isn't relevant ... So, what's the best way to go? `array<String^>^` to a `vector<char*>` to a `char * Bar[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are utility methods to convert a single string for you, but for the array, you'll need to do it yourself.

This is what I would do: First, convert to C++ classes, because they're convenient and handle most of the memory allocation that you need to deal with. Then, create the `char*[]` to point at the C++ objects.

```
void ManagedClass::Foo(array<String^>^ managedArray)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    for each (String^ managedStr in managedArray)
        vec.push_back(marshal_as<std::string>(managedStr));

    char** unmanagedArray = new char*[vec.size()];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        unmanagedArray[i] = vec[i].c_str();

    NativeClass * MyNativeClass = new NativeClass();
    MyNativeClass->Foo(unmanagedArray);

    delete[] unmanagedArray;
}
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not at a compiler at the moment, there may be minor syntax errors.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for this example. I modified `NativeClass::Foo(char * Bar[])` to `NativeClass::Foo(char ** Bar)`, cast `unmanagedArray[i] = (char *)vec[i].c_str();` and got it to work.